# Argument names function R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am trying to create a function, and I want to be able to get the names of my arguments , and I used formalArgs (I found it as answer to a question like mine) for that but I don't get what I want (I even tried formals()).

This is my function

```
entropy= function(...) 
{
rest of the code
print(formalArgs(entropy))
}
```

when I call the function entropy(h1,h2,h3)
the formalArgs prints

```
$...
```

but I want to be able to get

```
h1,h2,h3
```

is there a way to do that ? 
thanks :)

Comment: You probably want something like `all.names(match.call())[-1]`. What would be the expected output of `entropy(h1, h2 = 1, h3)`?

Comment: the all.names(match.call())[-1] works perfectly . Thank you !

Comment: or maybe `print(names(list(...)))` given `h1`, `h2` & `h3` are defined already?

Comment: already tried print(names(list(...))), and I get NULL , but thanks !

Comment: Even if you run that function using `entropy(h1=1,h2=2,h3=3)`?

Comment: didn't actually try it like this since my h1 h2 h3 are matrices and I need them later on in the function :)

Answer (score 0):

Use substitute() to fetch the unaltered input and deparse it.

```
entropy= function(h1,h2,h3) 
{
  #rest of the code
  print(c( deparse(substitute(h1)), deparse(substitute(h2)), deparse(substitute(h3))))
}

entropy(a,b,c)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: It is customary to accept the answer if it works for you.